# can I get serial number of android device using php code?

Tags: java, php, android

If I use a simple code from Java and it get serial number of android device, now how do I use the Java file in PHP code and when the user clicked a button, my php code uses the Java file and gets the serial number.

Note: I do not want to use Tomcat server and I want to use Apache server only.

Comment: If you want an answer, read up on [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make your question better.

Comment: I read the " How To ask", but I do not understand and I can not recognize my wrong in my question, and  Where is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can only get unique ids in native code on the device, not in Java code on an external Tomcat server nor in any language on a webserver because the UUID is not sent in the HTTP headers

Comment: thank you very much. you say " because the UUID is not sent in the HTTP headers". but there are a site such as " whatismyandroidversion.com" and it get android version when users go to the site and users see the version android in the site.

Comment: @rezas1000 Serial number of device and Android OS version are not the same thing. If you just want OS version that is in the `user-agent` header.

Comment: No you are incorrect when you say "nor in any language on a webserver". UUIDs can be fetched via cordova if the device has it, see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Comment: @DritanX Phonegap doesn't involve a webserver, right? Its just basically a pack of html/javascript/css files on the device itself, running in a native app wrapper.

Comment: No there is no server-side code being executed but you expect to write a webpage only to be used locally through your lan? this solution is acceptable for users trying to get the UUID regardless of whether it's from headers sent to server or JS running on client...

Comment: @DritanX PhoneGap isn't a webpage on your lan but on the device itself. So what you're expecting is the answer to a totally different question than what was asked.

Comment: What you say is redundant. All pages run on the client device. If you view this page from your device it is fetched from the world wide web onto your device. You could alternatively save a cache of this exact page on a box somewhere on your lan. If you were to visit the cached version from your lan this page would also run on your client.

Comment: @DritanX You're thinking that PhoneGap is running standard javascript. No no no. PhoneGap has access to extra functions that arent' in standard javascript. PhoneGap is a NATIVE application that exposes NATIVE functions to javascript that is running within its NATIVE wrapper which javascript running in a browser does not have access to.

Comment: Wow! So it's an WebView wrapper that clients use to get custom fields? That is a joke of a service. Why wouldn't the app developer create his own web view with *exactly* what s/he needs rather than import this heavy app? Thanks for clarifying that and while it doesn't answer the question directly, it IS still an acceptable solution for those apps that have phonegap bundled with the app.

Comment: @DritanX If you're talking about an app on the device that sends the information to the server, yes, PhoneGap will work for you. If you're talking about being able to detect the uid of any device that comes to your website through whatever browser (which is what I thought the question was about) then it won't. But yes, if you have an app on the device certainly you can collect the uid via the app and then send it on to your webserver.

Comment: There's no other way to use phonegap than to install it with your app. Otherwise, as a web dev, you're relying on a 3rd party app to exist on the mobile device and if they don't have it you can redirect them to phonegap... but if you're doing that, you might as well install your own app and get even more stuff or custom fields or establish a secure socket connection outside of your web app and into native so now you can insert contacts or messages ...whatever you need out of your own app